# Intergrate JSON into wordpress

Tags: api, json

is there an easy way to intergrate a JSON script in to Wordpress?
I have a JSON API from a thirt party sorftware company which i have to use so customers can create an account on our site.

Thanks in advanced for you reply

Comment: Yes, JSON can be integrated. But can you be a little clearer - what part of WordPress are you wanting to integrate with what JSON? Are you wanting to have visitors create WordPress accounts that then call an API to create mirror accounts in another system? Or are you wanting visitors to the WordPress site to register for accounts that only get saved through the API, then view data on WordPress? Or some other process?

Comment: Hi WebElain, first off thanks for your reply. What i want to happen is that customers be able to create an account so they can place orders on our website. However, the software my company use for that is Easytrans and they provide an JSON API. So my question is how to import or integrate this API? This API redirect and interacts with their software. I hope i explained it well.